# Flight number from Manchester to Limoges 7 days ago

Tags: france, flight-search-engines, ryanair, manchester

Can anyone please tell me the flight number from 7 days ago for above flight on 10 March from Manchester to Limoges
This flight was over 6 hrs delayed
Flight scheduled for 13.20 and to land at Limoges by 16.05
My ticket with Ryanair does not give me flight number only ticket reference
I am required to give the flight number for compensation.

Answer (score 2):

To further the correct answer from @DavidSupportsMonica

FR38 is indeed the correct flight you are trying to search for, as the flight on March 10th 2023 has been delayed by 6 hours

It was scheduled to arrive at 16:05 and landed 6 hours later at 22:29 (data from flightradar24)

Answer (score 1):

Airlines often fly the same flights repeatedly, on the same day(s) of the week and at the same time(s), using the same flight number. If "7 days ago" refers to a flight on March 10, 2023, then it's very likely the same flight will again occur next week, on March 24, 2023.

Both [Google Flghts](https://www.google.com/travel/flights/search?tfs=CBwQAhoeagcIARIDTUFOEgoyMDIzLTAzLTI0cgcIARIDTElHcAGCAQsI____________AUABSAGYAQI) and Ryanair's [buy-a-ticket page](https://www.ryanair.com/us/en/trip/flights/select?adults=1&teens=0&children=0&infants=0&dateOut=2023-03-24&dateIn=&isConnectedFlight=false&isReturn=false&discount=0&promoCode=&originIata=MAN&destinationIata=LIG&tpAdults=1&tpTeens=0&tpChildren=0&tpInfants=0&tpStartDate=2023-03-24&tpEndDate=&tpDiscount=0&tpPromoCode=&tpOriginIata=MAN&tpDestinationIata=LIG) show Ryanair's flight FR38 from Manchester UK to Limoges FR, departing 1320 and arriving 1605, on Friday, March 24.

Ryanair flights on the same route after March 24 do not always go on Friday, but they do show the same route, same times, and the same flight number.

Thus, you were on Ryanair's flight FR38.